# How can I exclude all the elements below a number in a vector, and at the same time remove the corresponding element in the other vector in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two vectors, representing the height and weight of the 97 participants in a research, now I want to remove all the observation with height below 2m, and at the same time remove the corresponding observations in the weight vector. What functions should I use in R?

Comment: Sry guys I think I have not stated the question clearly.

Comment: I have a dataset here and there are two variables one called height, one called weight, and i use them to construct a simple linear regression. Suddenly I find that I recorded some participants with heights below 1m40cm, I found these participants are potential outliers because might affect the regression. There I want to remove them from the dataset and construct a log transformation to the regression model. How can I remove them and get a new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a boolean vector by comparing height vector and use that to filter both height and weight vectors.

```
height.check <- height < 200  # taken in cm scale
height <- height[!height.check]
weight <- weight[!height.check]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a data frame (use `?data.frame` for info)

```
x <- data.frame("Participant"=paste("Participant",1:97,sep="_"),
                "Height"=height_vector,
                "Weight"=weight_vector)
```

where `height_vector` and `weight_vector` are your data

```
x2 <- x[x$Height >= 2,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you gave us no data, I produced some fake data.

```
> height <- c(2.0, 1.75, 2.15, 1.98, 1.45)  ## in meters
> weight <- c(200, 178, 180, 198, 205)      ## in pounds
```

We can remove the unwanted values using vector operations:

```
> height[height < 2.0]
[1] 1.75 1.98 1.45
> weight[height < 2.0]
[1] 178 198 205
```

But it's best to put the two vectors together into a `data.frame` and then subset on the condition that height is less than 2.  This will automatically remove the corresponding weights.

```
> d <- data.frame(height = c(2.0, 1.75, 2.15, 1.98, 1.45),
                  weight = c(200, 178, 180, 198, 205))
> d[d$height < 2, ]
  height weight
2   1.75    178
4   1.98    198
5   1.45    205
```

Comment: I modified my question:I have a dataset here and there are two variables one called height, one called weight, and i use them to construct a simple linear regression. Suddenly I find that I recorded some participants with heights below 1m40cm, I found these participants are potential outliers because might affect the regression. There I want to remove them from the dataset and construct a log transformation to the regression model. How can I remove them and get a new data?